# Shouldn't be community wiki, should I re-ask?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

3 years ago, before I understood what 'wiki' means in the SE world, I asked a question and converted it to community wiki. That was a mistake as it's really just a normal ol' question. 
Here it is: [How to delete system default printer forms?](https://serverfault.com/questions/64607/how-to-delete-system-default-printer-forms)

I've not uncovered a usable answer, it's still an issue for my office, and this week decided to sacrifice 80% of my meagre reputation to see if anything new has come up in the last 3 years. I'm now thinking that was throwing good money after bad, as no one really wants to spend time on CWs. Is it okay to re-ask, and thereby hope to garner enough interest that it might get some real answers? or will I just get slapped down for it?

(There is the alternative explanation that I've just simply asked a question that has no answer. I'm doubtful of that, I'm just not that smart or original!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see no reason for it to remain a Wiki; *CW status revoked*.

If you had re-asked, someone would have noticed eventually and it would be closed as a dupe.

Comment: oh, I thought CW was a one-way trip. thanks Chris!

Comment: Mods can do/undo almost anything a user can do. The community team and Devs can do anything... You just have to have a good reason to inspire us with, we're lazy.